# How to resolve files order in tsconfig

Tags: file, typescript, dependencies, tsconfig

I am migrating my project to typescript. I add files to tsconfig, but for each file I have to track its dependencies manually to put it in correct order. Is there a way files ordering can be done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way files ordering can be done automatically?

Use a module system e.g. commonjs with a module loader e.g. webpack.

## More

Here is a quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html